# How to include all elements of an array in a SQL query?

Tags: c#, sql, arrays, linq

Basically, the idea is to match data from one DataTable with another. 
In the first DT, there are 20 different columns in one row that I create an array from, and there is another DT with thousands of rows, two columns each. I need to select all of those rows in the second DT that are found among all of the 20 different variables in the array (so, I go row by row in the first table).

Can I do this in one query?

```
for (int x = 0; x < 20; x++) //this fills up the array from the 20 columns of dt1
{
   numbers[x] = Convert.ToInt16(dt1.Rows[i]["n" + (x+1)]);
}
var filtered = dt2.Select("Col1 = " + (any of the numbers[]) + " AND Col2 = " + (any of the numbers[]));
```

So clearly the line in question is the last one. I'm not sure if it's possible to do so.

I'm new here and I'm new to C# as well.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Just to clarify, you're wanting to iterate over each column in DT1 (20 columns), and match each one against BOTH columns of each row in DT2?  If there's a match in either of the 2 columns, project into a new DataTable ("filtered" DT2)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this SQL on `DataTable`:

```
var numbersAsString = numbers.Select(x => x.ToString()).Aggregate((x,y) => x + "," + y);
var filtered = dt2.Select("Col1 in (" + numbersAsString  + ") AND Col2 in (" + numbersAsString  + ")");
```

First you create string from your `Array` that looks like this: '1,3,4,5' and then checks in SQL if Col1 or Col2 value is in the array.

Comment: I chose this approach, because SQL was better in this scenario and it became the final solution. Thank you so much gzaxx! :)

Comment: If you'd create a string-array: String.Join(",",numbersStr) would do the first line easier ;)

Answer (score 2):

You could convert your data table into an enumerable and filter the data with LINQ.

Something like this:

`var filtered = dt2.AsEnumerable().Where(m => numbers.Contains(m.Col1) && numbers.Contains(m.Col2))`;

Comment: While this is more elegant (especially in C#), the solution from gzaxx was much more appropriate for me. Thank you for your quick response Raúl, I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

Both of the above approaches work well.  Without knowing whether or not your DataSets are strongly-typed, however (and using a single query instead of requiring dt1 to be projected into an array):

```
var filtered = dt2.AsEnumerable().Where(row => dt1.Rows[0].ItemArray.Contains(row[0]) ||
                                               dt1.Rows[0].ItemArray.Contains(row[1]));
```

Comment: No problem suntime, I'm happy we could help! :)